# Create inner method where "new" takes keyword arguments

Tags: struct, julia

Say I have the struct

```
struct MyStruct

    foo
    bar
    
    function MyStruct(foo::Number, bar::String)
         new(bar = "hello", foo = 2)
    end

end
```

then I get an error `ERROR: syntax: "new" does not accept keyword arguments around <path to file>`

Is it true that `new` can't be used with kwargs, or am I missing something? In my real code I have 20 fields thus I would prefer using keyword arguments in `new` to ensure that they the correct values are indeed set for the correct field.

Comment: from what I understand, you should use the keyword arguments in the line `function MyStruct(foo::Number, bar::String)`

Comment: Or maybe you wanted `new("hello", 2)`. The parameters of `new` are not named parameters, the assign the struct members in order by position.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to set this up:

- Use `Base.@kwdef` or `Parameters.@with_kw`, both macros automatically define keyword constructors for your struct (with default arguments). This is very useful if your struct has many fields that have certain default parameters. See also [Julia doc on @kwdef](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Base.@kwdef)

```
Base.@kwdef struct MyStruct
    foo = 2
    bar = "hello"
end
```

- Define a keyword constructor yourself. This is especially useful, if you want to have a combination of regular input arguments and keywords, so something like:

```
struct MyStruct
    foo
    bar 
end

MyStruct(foo; bar="hello") = MyStruct(foo, bar)  # one could also write this as an inner constructor
```

or

```
struct MyStruct
    foo
    bar 

    MyStruct(foo; bar="hello") = new(foo, bar)  # now as an inner constructor 
end
```

Comment: Here you are still using positional arguments for "new". We can't use keyword-arguments for "new" without creating the constructor?

Comment: Yes, ```new``` always wants positional arguments. As I wrote, if you have structs with many parameters, personally I'd use ```@kwdef```, it's very handy.

Comment: You can also combine outer constructors with ```@kwdef```. Generally, I write much more outer constructers, than inner constructors with ```new```.